ARCore Extensions for Unity 2023 fails to build (checkReleaseDuplicateClasses)
My build keeps failing with "Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.", by just installing ARCore Extensions in a new, clean project in Unity.
I understand that this error occurs because there are conflicts with AndroidX libraries and support libraries, but I have yet to find an answer or solution on how to build it without running into this error.
There are several support/androidx libs that fail like this:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime

My steps:

Create a new 3D project in Unity 2023.2.20f1.
Install AR Foundation, ARCore and ARKit 5.1.3 in Package Manager.
Setup XR (AR Session, XR Origin), remove Vulkan etc in Player Settings (Following the guide).
Install ARCore Extensions using git link.
Add "ARCORE_USE_ARF_5" to "Scripting Define Symbols" in "Player -> Other Settings"
Add a "ARCoreExtensionsConfig" to the "ARCore Extensions" GameObject.
Enable "Geospatial Mode" and "Streetscape Geometry Mode" in ARCoreExtensionsConfig.
Build an APK (Fails!).

I expect the the build to work within the editor with minimal effort or changes to configurations. It feels like a bug rather than a faulty configuration, so I have opened an issue on GitHub.
I've tried installing both versions of ARCore Extensions, the one with bundled libs and the one without (the tarball, ARCore Extensions Lite).
Using External Dependency Manager, combinations of "Force Resolve", "Resolve" and "Remove Resolved Libraries" options. Removing libraries removes some files from Assets/Android without affecting the error.
During some combination of attempts it managed to build, but Unity backscreens or the camera does not work, which indicates that the actual required libs are not included in the build at all (So therefor no conflict either).
I've tried enabling custom gradle files that are managed by External Dependency Manager, same error. I've tried gradle files with androidx and jetifier enabled.
EDIT:
I've now confirmed that it works in Unity 2022.3.26f1, so it's an issue related to Unity 2023.2.X.
